# flash player still blocks the pulldown menu even if wmode set to transparent

Tags: flash, video, transparency

We know set wmode to transparent in flash player can reveal pulldown menu behind the flash player but this seems not always true. Take a look at this url: http://video.udn.com , when the video starts to play, it still block the pulldown menu. I've used browser debug tool to check the code of that video player, it did set wmode to transparent. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

With wmode transparent you can show content under the Flash. Try to set wmode to opaque:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Also make sure you set the correct z-indexes on the divs.